# Best place to put outlets/actions in a large Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm developing my first application in Objective-C, so I fully expect it to be not quite "best practice" at this point but I think I may be starting to scatter my code/outlets/actions in the wrong places. So I'd like to know where the best place would be to put these things. Here's a brief outline of my app:

I have an NSTabView at the top containing some NSTextFields and NSButtons, so I have what I've called a TabViewController with all the outlets/actions for anything inside it. Through code I now want to be able to set the default action for the text fields to be one of two buttons (so I can't wire it up by ctrl+dragging, one assumes). I thought I'd do this in my TabViewController's init: method but this doesn't seem to work, so I guess it's not being called as I would have hoped?

```
[_myTextFieldOutlet setTarget:self]; 
[_myTextFieldOutlet setAction:@selector(oneOfTheMethods:)];
```

So, I was about to drag some outlets to my AppDelegate thinking I should do the above from within the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method, but this would now require outlets for these text fields in two files, and not just the TabViewController. I'm now starting to think I'm creating a mess. Presumably "self" wouldn't be right if I did the above within AppDelegate and perhaps oneOfTheMethods: couldn't be seen, either? I haven't tried that yet.

Is there a better way to do this? I wanted to get away from having a hundred methods in one class and having a controller for each of the main containers in the GUI seemed reasonable enough. But when methods in one controller need to refer to other controllers then I'm beginning to think I'm doing it wrong. I'm much more familiar with c# .NET and would easily get the same thing done there without a problem, but Objective-C and XCode still have me second-guessing myself most of the time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest reading Mike Ash's [NSblog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/); I learned a lot. Here's how he suggests [organizing a Cocoa app](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html).

> The fundamental UI component of a Cocoa app is the NSWindow, and there
>   are many different ways to instantiate and manage them, but there is
>   only one correct way: for each type of window, there should be a
>   separate nib file, and a specialized NSWindowController subclass. I'll
>   walk through what this means and how to do it, a topic suggested by
>   reader Mike Shields.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That certainly looks like good advice. I was also wondering how to share data between all the files (which I didn't ask above); e.g., I also have a TableViewController whose backing array I want to access/modify from one of the methods in my TabViewController. I tried to create a static/class variable to house the array but these don't seem as straight forward in Objective C like they are in c#, so then I created a getter class method to return the "NSMutableArray *_tableContents" var I defined after #import & before @implementation in the .m file. Probably dodgy also? :-)

Comment: Do you know how to use Key Value Coding, Key Value Observing, and bindings? If you don't, you are working too hard. The backing array for the controller is typically the model, and perhaps belongs in its own object. KVC and bindings makes it easy to access properties in objects using a key (the string name of the property) and KVO gives you automagic notification that a property changed. Mike Ash has some info, Apple docs have it, and here is another link as well http://tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/how-cocoa-bindings-work-via-kvc-and-kvo/

Comment: I've read briefly about KVC/KVO in the few ebooks I've bought so far (they don't dwell on them much). Maybe I'm diving in too quickly into creating something but as soon as I learned how to add an object to XCode and make it the controller/data-source for my NSTableView, and given that it required an array, well... I guess I just declared that array as part of the controller and moved on. Obviously things are now starting to unravel, so perhaps I'd best change to KVC/KVO. Thanks. I've also bought Prag Prog's "Core Data 2nd Ed." but haven't got around to reading it yet. Perhaps I should :-)

Comment: I'd suggest you *avoid* KVO, bindings and perhaps even Core Data in your first project — they are quite powerful, but particularly bindings can be horrendously difficult to debug.

Comment: That's probably why I haven't gone near them yet (but know I will need them eventually). Right now I would be happy with knowing exactly where to declare the NSMutableArray so that other classes/methods can deal with it. I'm considering making my AppDelegate the delegate/data source for the tableview and putting all my outlets/actions on that same class also. I'll still create another class to offload a lot of the mutating logic but it seems I'm spreading all my outlets/actions across far too many files and that's creating all kinds of nightmares in modifying the array.

Comment: If Cocoa is anything like Cocoa-touch you would have a series of custom view controllers whose job it would be, in your case, to handle gathering the data from the user and they would pass the data to data controller objects that would do the data manipulation and saving or deleting  etc. Finally you have data holding objects that are stored in active memory and references to them are passed among the different controllers using segues or delegation depending on the relationship of the controllers. Each view controller will have links to the text fields that are in its view in its header file.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it some more I think I just need to wire everything up to my AppDelegate, but the AppDelegate can merely act as a broker between the GUI and other classes to do the main logic. If the AppDelegate holds the NSMutableArray as an ivar, and does all the dispatching to other classes to do the manipulation, then that effectively solves my problem of getting a reference to the array behind the table view. I don't have to worry about the TabViewController having to get the array from the TableViewController if the AppDelegate is the intermediary. Thanks everyone! :-)